# Script PHP que lista e edita outros arquivos

Tags: php

Como posso criar um script onde o mesmo irá listar todos os arquivos que estão na pasta principal e nas subpastas para que possa editar os arquivos e substituir com o que foi editado?

Se possível tbm ter uma função para deletar o arquivo se quiser..

Alguém tem alguma noção de como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listar tudo de uma vez é uma péssima ideia, a não ser que você apenas deseje executar algo nestes arquivos e pastas, mas não listar tudo.

Na verdade o que você quer é um "file manager" (gerenciador de arquivos):

- [File manager PHP no Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=file%20manager%20php&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

> Quero deixar você atento a uma coisa, este código pode falhar, independente de quem escrever ou reescrever, se for usar em produção recomendo procurar ferramentas já conceituadas, então leve estes códigos como caso de estudo, ou então teste muito bem os códigos a seguir.
>
> Em servidores baseados em GNU/Linux existem permissões de pastas e niveis de acesso, portanto talvez nem todo arquivo seja acessivel, claro que suponho que os arquivos serão gerados pelo proprio script php, então você não terá este problema com o "proprietário do arquivo"

### Para caso de estudos

Primeiro crie um arquivo global.php, pois vamos usar mais de um arquivo e neste caso é melhor manter as configurações em um só e usar `include`, crie um arquivo chamado `global.php`:

```
<?php
define('DATA_FOLDER', '/home/user/arquivos'); //Troque pela pasta que deseja editar e navegar
```

Se for listar uma pasta (o que eu recomendo) por vez pode fazer assim (chamado `navegar.php`):

```
<?php
include 'global.php';

$ap = DATA_FOLDER;
$dir = '/';

if (empty($_GET['pasta']) === false) {
   $dir = '/' . trim($_GET['pasta'], '/');
}

if (isset($_GET['deletar']) && file_exists($ap . $dir)) {
    echo '<a href="deletar.php?arquivo=', $ap . $dir,'">Quer realmente deletar o arquivo "', $ap , $dir, '"?</a><hr>';
}

if (is_dir($ap . $dir)) {
    $dh = opendir($ap . $dir);
    if ($dh) {
        echo '<ul>';

        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
               continue;
            }

            $acessivel = false;
            $atual = $ap . $dir . '/' . $file;

            if (is_dir($atual)) {
                 echo '<li> <a href="navegar.php?pasta=', $dir, '/', $file, '">', $file,'</a>';
                 $acessivel = true;
            } else if (is_file($atual)) {
                 echo '<li>', $file,' <a href="editar.php?arquivo=', $dir, '/', $file, '">[Editar]</a>';
                 $acessivel = true;
            }

            if ($acessivel) {
                echo ' <a href="deletar.php?arquivo=', $dir, '/', $file, '&amp;deletar=1">[Deletar]</a> </li>';
            }
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>

<hr>

<a href="navegar.php">Voltar a raiz</a>
```

Quando acessar `navegar.php?pasta=` ele vai apontar o novo diretório.

O `editar.php` lê e grava o arquivo, note que usei `LOCK_EX` pra evitar mais de uma pessoa deletar enquanto grava.

```
<?php
include 'global.php';

if (empty($_GET['arquivo'])) {
    echo 'Arquivo não definido';
    exit;
}

$ap = DATA_FOLDER;
$arquivo = $ap . '/' . $_GET['arquivo'];

if (false === is_file($arquivo)) {
    echo 'Arquivo não inacessivel ou invalido:', $arquivo;
    exit;
}

echo 'Você está editado: ', $arquivo, '<br>';

if (isset($_POST['conteudo'])) {
    file_put_contents($arquivo, $_POST['conteudo'], LOCK_EX);
}
?>

<form action="editar.php?arquivo=<?php echo $_GET['arquivo']; ?>" method="POST">
     <textarea name="conteudo" cols="150" rows="50"><?php
          echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($arquivo));
     ?></textarea><br>
     <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>

<hr>

<a href="navegar.php?pasta=<?php echo dirname($_GET['arquivo']); ?>">Voltar para navegação</a>
```

E por fim o deletar.php:

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['arquivo'])) {
    echo 'Arquivo não definido';
    exit;
}

include 'global.php';

$ap = DATA_FOLDER;
$arquivo = $ap . '/' . $_GET['arquivo'];

if (is_dir($arquivo)) {
    //Deleta pasta recursivamente, pois não é possivel deletar pastas que não estão vazias
    function recursive_rmdir($path) {
        if (is_dir($path) && ($dh = opendir($path))) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
                   continue;
                }

                $atual = $path . '/' . $file;

                if (is_dir($atual)) {
                    recursive_rmdir($atual);
                } else if (is_file($atual)) {
                    unlink($atual);
                } else {
                    echo $atual, ' é inacessivel<br>';
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
            rmdir($path);
        } else if (is_file($path)) {
            unlink($path);
        }
    }

    recursive_rmdir($arquivo);
} else if (is_file($arquivo)) {
   if (unlink($arquivo)) {
       echo 'Arquivo "', $arquivo,'" deletado com sucesso';
   } else {
       echo 'Falha ao deletar o arquivo "', $arquivo,'"';
   }
} else {
       echo 'Arquivo "', $arquivo,'" inacessivel';
}
?>

<hr>

<a href="navegar.php?pasta=<?php echo dirname($_GET['arquivo']); ?>">Voltar para navegação</a>
```

Funções usadas e que você deve estudar:

- Abre diretório: http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php
- Verifica se é arquivo: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php
- Veirifca se é pasta: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php
- Deleta arquivos: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php
- Deleta pastas vazias: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php
- Grava conteúdo em um arquivo (é binary-safe): http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
- Lê o conteúdo de um arquivo (é binary-safe): http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

### Para produção

Se for o caso de ambiente de produção recomendo usar aplicações já conceituadas como e devidamente testadas, como:

> Eu não testei, não sei se funcionam tão bem, mas tem repositório e controle de bugs

- http://www.mollify.org (Licença GPLv2, é repleto de funções, tem plugins, thumbnails, baseado em ajax)
- http://www.filerun.com (pago, mas parece ser bem avançado e é repleto de funções extras, como thumbnails e baseado em ajax)
- http://extplorer.sourceforge.net
- http://phpfm.sourceforge.net
- http://www.osfilemanager.com
- http://pfn.sourceforge.net

Comment: Nossa mano.. Vlw pelas dicas e ideia... Vou estudar o script e as funções... Brigadão.. Hehe.. só uma pergunta... nele é possível editar e gravar as alterações?

Comment: @PedroQuezado corrigi o deletar.php !

Comment: muito bom @GuilhermeNascimento